# html tag input id changes with server restart?

Tags: input

I am using id element of input tag and type is text of html. I am referring id to check wheater element is present in html page or not. My question if web server/app server is restarted or changed does its id changes?

the example tag

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way the id will change is if you set up some way for it to do so (random Id on startup).  I don't know why you would want to do that though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have written java code to test web page but I was not able track using the label. I tried with id it was working, when discussed with my friend he said id will change after restarting server. I posted it and wanted to clear it.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel this answers your question, please mark it as such so it does not appear as unanswered to the community.